# Generate list of columns: Columns are in alphabetical order instead of table order

Tags: oracle, select, toad

*Toad for Oracle 12:*

I want to automatically generate a list of columns from a table -- so that I can quickly write a query that includes a subset of the table columns.

In Toad, I can do this by:

1. Right-clicking the table name in the Schema Browser
2. Generate Statement
3. Select

[image]

Result:

A list of columns gets copied to the clipboard. I can paste the column names into the Editor window and write my query.

---

Question:

Toad seems to generate the list of columns in *alphabetical order*. I would prefer to work with the columns in the order they appear in the table, instead of alphabetical order.

Is there a way in Toad to quickly generate a list of table columns -- using the column order from the original table?

- It would be helpful if it were a simple *list* of column names, not a full CREATE TABLE script, since a full script would include extra text. I would need to manually remove that extra text from the list, which somewhat defeats the purpose of "quickly generating a list of column names".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skip the TOAD UI and use the query below. I added a comma to the end if needed.

```
select column_name ||','
from user_tab_columns 
where table_name = '<yourtable>'
order by column_id
```

Take some time to read about the Oracle [Data Dictionary](http://www.dba-oracle.com/concepts/data_dictionary.htm).  which is very useful when you need to get metadata about an oracle object such as table, views, etc.

Answer (score 1):

A modified version of @OldProgrammer's answer:

---

In my case, as a non-dba, I had to use `all_tab_columns` (and specify the table owner), since `user_tab_columns` didn't return any records for me.

```
select 
    column_name ||','
from 
    all_tab_columns 
where 
    owner = 'MAXIMO'
    and table_name = 'PO'
order by 
    column_id
```